# Prepend (add character) to string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a SQL table called ID (ex. 1234,12345). I want to add a "LM" to every record in that column: LM1234, LM12345, etc

Answer (score 6):

We suppose that ID column has varchar/char/... or any other string related data type., so try this:

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET [COL] = 'LM'+COL
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `id` is a string, just do an update:

```
update t
     set id = 'LM' + id;
```

If column is not a string, then you need to make it one first:

```
alter table t alter id varchar(255);

update t
     set id = 'LM' + id;
```

Also, you could just add a computed column to do the calculation:

```
alter table t add lm_id as (concat('LM', column))
```

Comment: Thank you! Stupid mistake I was doing "LM" not 'LM'

Answer (score 1):

Create a view vwID:

```
CREATE VIEW vwID AS
SELECT "LM" + ID AS ID, <list the rest of your columns here>
;
```

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT() should work fine:

```
update [TABLE_NAME] set col=CONCAT('LM', col) where col is not NULL
```

Comment: love ti,  since this solution can be used with SQLAlchemy